# General formula for distinct k colourings of a regular n-gon

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we are to colour edges of a regular n-gon with k-colours. How do we count the number of such distinct coloured n-gons?

I know that one way to count these is to use burnside's lemma, but im not able to apply it.

Comment: There is this [fact sheet](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3216181/) on necklaces and bracelets.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Thanks!