# Possible Arrangements at a Round Table

Tags: combinatorics

> If I have $10$ large chairs and $5$ small chairs to be arranged at a round table, how many different ways are there to arrange them?

There are $15!$ possible arrangements; however, since the $10$ large chairs are identical and the $5$ small chairs are identical, $15!$ must be divided by both $10!$ and $5!$. This equals to $3003$. Additionally, since the table is round, I must divide by $15$. However, dividing by $15$ results in an answer of $200.2$ which makes no sense.

Am I incorrect in dividing by $15$? If so, why is my final answer a decimal?

Comment: Some of the patterns have other symmetries. For instance, consider the string $LLSLLSLLSLLSLLS$.  There are only three ways to cyclically "rotate" that to get a different string, not fifteen.

Comment: The following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820079) may prove useful.

Answer (score 2):

If we had fifteen distinct objects, we could arrange them in a row in $15!$ ways.  In a circular permutation, only the relative order of the objects matters.  There are two ways to handle this:

- Pick one of the objects as a reference point.  Relative to this object, the other $14$ objects can be arranged in $14!$ ways as we proceed clockwise around the circle.
- Break a circular arrangement between two objects.  Now place the objects in a line as we proceed clockwise around the circle from the point where we made the break.  There are $15$ ways we could do this, one to the left of each object.  Hence, there are $15$ linear arrangements corresponding to each circular arrangement.  Since there are $15!$ linear arrangements of $15$ objects, there are
  $$\frac{15!}{15} = \frac{15 \cdot 14!}{15} = 14!$$
  circular permutations of $15$ distinct objects.

In general, there are $(n - 1)!$ circular permutations of $n$ distinct objects.

In this case, we have ten indistinguishable large chairs and five indistinguishable small chairs to arrange in a circle.  As you observed, there are
$$\binom{15}{5}$$
ways to arrange the objects in a line.  If we divide by $15$ to obtain the number of circular arrangements, we do not get an integer because as @lulu pointed out in the comments, the circular arrangement in which there are exactly two large chairs between each pair of small chairs has just three corresponding linear arrangements:
$$LLSLLSLLSLLSLLS$$
$$LSLLSLLSLLSLLSL$$
$$SLLSLLSLLSLLSLL$$
Therefore, when we divide by $15$, we count this particular arrangement $3/15 = 1/5$ times.  We want to count it once, so we must add $4/5$ to your answer. Hence, the number of distinct circular arrangements of $10$ indistinguishable large chairs and $5$ indistinguishable small chairs is
$$\frac{1}{15}\binom{15}{5} + \frac{4}{5} = 201$$